# How surprising is this result on the diophantine equation $x(x+1)...(x+n-1) = y^n+k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

A number of years ago, I proved the following result:

For any integer $k$, the number of positive integral solutions to
 $x(x+1)...(x+n-1) = y^n+k$
with $n \ge 3$ is finite 
(i.e., there are only a finite number of $(x, y, n)$ satisfying this equation
for any $k$).

It is pretty clear that for any fixed $k$ and $n$ there are only a finite number of $x$ and $y$ (you can prove that $y \le |k|$), but the fact that there are only a finite number of $n$ came as a surprise to me. I initially proved that $n < e|k|$ and later derived much stricter bounds.

The way I phrased this is "The product of $n$ consecutive integers is almost never close to an $n$-th power."

My question is whether this result is surprising?

Thanks.

Comment: Surprise is relative. Perhaps you might like to ask a more precise question, like "are there any common heuristics which suggest that this is the obvious answer" or "are there elementary techniques which quickly yield this result"?

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan:  I seem to recall a general result that when the sum of degrees of a Diophantine equation (here 2/n) is less than 1 you should expect a finite number of solutions, but a quick search doesn't turn it up.  Maybe this would answer the question.

Comment: @Ross: this should follow from Scott Carnahan's answer in the linked MO post, but it only gives the result for fixed $n$.

Answer (score 3):

The result is not surprising in the sense that standard probabilistic heuristics suggest it to be true. In the interval $[2^d, 2^{d+1})$ there are $2^d$ numbers. Of those numbers, $O(d \cdot 2^{d/3})$ are perfect third powers or higher, so the probability that a number in this interval is a perfect third power or higher is $O(d \cdot 2^{-2d/3})$. The probability that a number in this interval is of the form $x(x+1)...(x+n-1) - k$ for some $n \ge 3$ should be approximately the same, and *if we assume that the two events are independent*, then the probability that a solution exists to your Diophantine equation with $y^n \in [2^d, 2^{d+1})$ is $O(d^2 \cdot 2^{-4d/3})$.

The sum of these probabilities over all $d$ converges. A heuristic application of [Borel-Cantelli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) then suggests that the number of solutions is finite.

Of course, this argument also applies, incorrectly, to $n = 2$. Here there is algebraic structure which violates the independence assumption. But this structure doesn't generalize to higher $n$, and I guess this can be made precise by Faltings' theorem for fixed $n$.

Speaking of which, Scott Carnahan's answer to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56011/why-should-i-believe-the-mordell-conjecture) about the Mordell conjecture may be more convincing to you, as it correctly excludes the case $n = 2$. (Take the sum over all $d \ge 3$, in the notation of his answer.)

Answer (score 0):

BTW, here is how I converted the bound on $y$ to a bound on $n$:

Since $2(n/e)^n < n!$,

$$2(n/e)^n < n! \le  x(x+1)...(x+n-1) = y^n+k.$$

Using the corrected bound on $y$ of $y \le |k|$,

$$2(n/e)^n < |k|^n + |k| \le 2|k|^n$$

so $n/e < |k|$ or $n < e|k|$.

I did this over 40 years ago, but I still remember thinking that this was magic,
somehow pulling the result out of thin air.

Comment: Nothing particularly magical seems to be going on here given that $y \le |k|$: you're just using the fact that factorials grow faster than exponentials. What I'd really like to know is how you showed that $y \le |k|$.

Comment: I agree with Quaochu Yuan.

Answer (score 0):

It is a result of Erdos and Selfridge that the product of consecutive integers is never a power (with trivial exceptions). Perhaps something in their [paper](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1975-46.pdf) is of use here.